# Individual column searching using Data table in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, jquery, json

I just want to use custom search data table for each fields. I do have the 
following code. But, I'm facing to search the footer search,cause it does search, but no result.

NB:

When I tried to search using the footer search box, it said no data available. But it has data on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the datatable and column search before the content is even loaded. And you have two document ready functions. You need to add the event handler after you create the datatable in the success function.

Add the following code AFTER you create the datatable in the success function:

```
dataTableExample.columns().every( function () {
var that = this;

$( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
        that
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
    }
    } );
} );
```